# MATLAB: Toolbar pushbutton not receiving updated strings from figure handles.

Tags: matlab

I have a GUI with an edit box and a push button on the tool bar (well, more things than that, but those are the only things that matter!) Anyway, I have it so when you press the push button tool a variable is set to equal the string in the edit box. A simple `var = get(handles.edit1, 'string')`. However, when I go straight from entering the value in the box to clicking the pushbutton (without clicking anywhere else or pressing return), `var` is assigned the previous value in the edit box. Why is this? Is there any way to make sure the push button tool will pick out the correct value?

The GUI was made using guide, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the uipushtool callback is executing before the text box has time to 'validate'. There is surely a more elegant way to do that but this trick works:

You can use the `waitfor` command to tell the uipushtool callback to wait for the editable box to validate its input. Unfortunately is is not exactly enough so we'll have to:

1) pass the focus to a dummy control (I created a dummy `pushbutton` named pushbutton1 which does nothing. The focus could be send to any other dummy control.

2) now wait for the text box to validate its content.

3) When the text box is done, then retrieve the content the traditional way.

This method requires:
- A dummy control to send the focus to (but you can use a real one too)
- An dummy (or not) callback function for your editable box. (the `waitfor` instruction will wait for the callback to finish, if there is no callback, it will error

```
function uipushtool1_ClickedCallback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    uicontrol( handles.pushbutton1 ) ; %// pass the focus to a dummy control
    waitfor(handles.edit1,'String');   %// wait for the editable box to validate its content
    var = get(handles.edit1, 'string') ; %// now retrieve the editable box content

    set( handles.text1 , 'String' , var ) %// this can be deleted, just to verify the method

% --------------------------------------------------------------------

function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    %// This is the dummy callback function for the editable box
    %// Do absolutely nothing here (or do if you want ... your choice)
```

---

**EDIT**

as I feared, my initial solution was too dirty to be robust enough. With 2 (or more) textboxes, I tried a large number of things but without success. I dropped the waitfor, I noticed that in some case, when the uipushtool was pressed, the callback of the editbox would fire but the uipushtool would not execute at all ... so i tried to managed things directly from the editbox callback => from the editbox keypressedFcn send each character as we type to a variable ... but even this editbox callback doesn't know the content of the edit box at the time it is executed ?? (This [link](http://www.matlabexperthelp.com/2012/07/08/perform-action-when-key-is-pressed/) provide a very simple example to reproduce that).

So to my great own disappointment, I had to resort to an 'external' solution. (If you accept that it becomes very simple though). The trick is to retrieve the handle of the ***Java*** `EditBox` object. Once we have the handle, getting the "real time" content is just matter of converting the ***Java*** `string` into a ***Matlab*** `string`.

To retrieve the Java object handles, you need the function [FindJObj](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects/) from Matlab central.

Put that anywhere in your matlab path, then the code for your pushbutton become something like :
*To make sure there was no interferences between the text boxes and the uipushtools I made 2 separate uipushtools each controlling 1 editbox*

```
function uipushtool1_ClickedCallback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    jEditbox = findjobj(handles.edit1); %// get the handle of the java editbox #1
    var = char(jEditbox.getText) ; %// retrieve Java string and convert it to matlab string

    disp(['uipushtool1_ClickedCallback running. Textbox1 content = ' var ]) %// debug line, you can delete or comment that

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function uipushtool2_ClickedCallback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    jEditbox = findjobj(handles.edit2); %// get the handle of the java editbox #2
    var = char(jEditbox.getText) ; %// retrieve Java string and convert it to matlab string

    disp(['uipushtool2_ClickedCallback running. Textbox2 content = ' var ]) %// debug line, you can delete or comment that
```

Thanks to *Yair Altman* for the `findjobj` function, *and many other contributions for Matlab users.*

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know why you have to pass the focus to a dummy control? Thanks so much by the way!

Comment: @HRoot, I am not sure actually. I noticed that when the standard pushbutton was pressed it was working fine because the text box would validate before loosing focus ... while it was not doing that when the uipushbutton was pressed. So that was my first attempt at solving your problem (i.e. just send the focus to another control to force the text box to validate its content) ... but it wasn't enough, so i found the `uiwaitfor` solution, but it wasn't working on it's own either... yet when both trick are used it works. There is probably a good reason behind it but i haven't figured it out yet :)

Comment: It seems this only works if there is only one edit box. When I tried adding more the program would get stuck. I assume this is because of the `waitfor` function but I don't know how to get out of it. I tried using a second pushbutton dummy but that didn't change anything. Any ideas why this is happening? @Hoki

Comment: @HRoot. I knew it ... my first solution wasn't robust enough. I edited the answer for something that works ... but it is still a dirty trick.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your problem and created a new GUI using guide with only a pushbutton and an edit field. If I set the button callback to:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
get(handles.edit1,'string')
```

it always prints the current value of the edit field, no matter if I click somewhere else after entering the value or not. Which version of Matlab are you using? I've tested it using Matlab 2010a.

Comment: To reproduce the behaviour described, you have to use a `uipushtool` in a `toolbar` (not a simple pushbutton on the main gui). The problem come from the fact that when the uipushtool callback is executed, the validation of the text box didn't take place yet. I am trying to force this validation before the execution of the callback but without success yet.

Comment: @Benoit_11, what Hoki said is right, it works fine if its a push button but not if its a button in the toolbar

Comment: Oh shoot I somehow missed the fact that the pushbutton was in a toolbar sorry! I need more coffee I guess.

Comment: Oh, I missed the toolbar part as well, sorry.